# angular4 route issue by adding '%2f' character before path

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-router, angular4-router

reason of using nested route for me is handling dynamically icon and back button for every page.i have abstract route because when i click to back button route params disappear and i put an abstract path to keep `id` and `questionnaire` type parameter in url.my abstract path is `Questionaire`

```
 { path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent,data:{icon:'fa-home'} },
 { path: 'QuestionaireList', component: QuestionaireListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-list-ul',previousState:'/Home'} },
 { 
      path: 'Questionaire/:questionnaireType/:id',
      children:[ 
      { path: 'AddQuestionnaire', component: CreateQuestionnaireComponent,data:{icon:'fa-plus',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'} },
      { path: 'UpdateQuestionnaire', component: EditComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'} },
      { path: 'QuestionList', component: QuestionListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-pencil',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'} },
      { path: 'ImportQuestion',    component: ImportQuestionComponent,data:{icon:'fa-plus',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'}  },
      { path: 'MetaContentList', component: MetaContentListComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:'/QuestionaireList'} },
      { path: 'ModifyMetaContent/:metaContentId/:title', component: ModifyMetaContentComponent,data:{icon:'fa-database',previousState:'/MetaContentList'}},
    ]}
```

Also in `questionnaire.list.html` i link to every path by routerlink 
bellow is one my link :

```
[routerLink]="['/Questionaire',item.questionnaireType,item.id,'/UpdateQuestionnaire']"
```

this is my link :

```
 <a  class="primary small ui icon button" [routerLink]="['/Questionaire',item.questionnaireType,item.id,'/UpdateQuestionnaire']" >
                <i class="edit   icon"></i>
              </a>
```

I expected when i click on link i route to this address:

> .../Questionaire/1/b8b55b42-f39f-4359-93d0-0260ddf3827f/UpdateQuestionnaire

But this error occured

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:
>   'Questionaire/1/b8b55b42-f39f-4359-93d0-0260ddf3827f/%2FUpdateQuestionnaire'

actually routerlink add %2f before UpdateQuestionnaire.
why is this happening?
what's wrong in my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried removing the slashes in your Router link like so:

`[routerLink]=['Questionaire', item.questionnaireType, item.id, 'UpdateQuestionnaire']`?

There seems to be a problem with slashes in routerlink as described in this [post](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10570)

I would post this as a comment, but since I don't have enough reputation I will post this as an answer, sorry about that.

I hope this clears stuff up for you.

Kind regards Chris